# Which Grid/Table will be more suitable and easy to implement in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC3. I had used WebGrid and TableSorter in my project. But they are lacking at some place. So I would like to know if is there a better Grid/Table which has following facilities(of-course a free version):

> 1) Single and Multiple Column Sorting.
>
> 2) Sorting and Pagination through Ajax.
>
> 3) Filtering
>
> 4) SubGrid(Optional)
>
> 5) Light-weight and Less-coding
>
> 6) CRUD Operations

I am using List to get data from model in table/grid and I have to display more than 1000 number of Records.

Comment: have you tried [DataTables](http://datatables.net/)? I've used them in some of my project, and i think they are pretty decent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using jqgrid for a while with MVC 3 and razor. It's a very flexible and powerful tool and has the features you are looking for.
You'll find more information on its [page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).